# json_encode doesn't print anything

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the follow code which doesn't print anything:

```
$array = array();
while ($res = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($array, array(
        'value' => $res['pregunta'],
        'tokens' => explode(' ',$res['pregunta']),
        'url' => $res['id-cadena']
        ));
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

But when I use print_r it works correctly:

> ```
>     Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [value] => ¿Cuál es la obra de Pablo Picasso basada en triangulos?
> ```
>
> etc...

Have somebody had the same problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at the source...

Comment: `json_encode` is probably returning `FALSE` (which when `echo`ed is a blank string).  There's something in your array that it cannot encode.  Try to add `echo json_last_error_msg();` after your `echo json_encode($array);`.

Comment: Best guess - the data in your database is not in UTF encoding and when you are trying to json encode it - you are getting an error. Try to convert by using 

   mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", "YOUR ENCODING HERE");

when building the array $array.

Comment: `echo json_last_error_msg();` make the magic :D only fix error displayed